# remove a span tag from inside a div -after it was dynamaclly placed

Tags: jquery

The following code works:
-click text below empty div 
-create new span tag inside the empty div 
-place selected text into that span

What does not work: The span tags inside the '.shtuff'div cannot be removed when they are clicked.
and and place it into the empty '.shtuff' class div

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.shtuff li').click(function(){

    //both below work
     $('.display').append($("<span></span>").text($(this).text())); 
    //$('.display').append("<span>" + $(this).text() + "</span>");  

        });

        //for single use
    //$('.shtuff li').click(function(){$(this).empty();}


 $('.display').on('click', 'span', function(){$(this).empty(); });

      });//ready
     </script>
```

css:

```
<style>
.display span{background-color:#ccc;margin-left:3px;}
.display{border:1px solid; width:300px;hieght:100px}
ul li {list-style-type:none;}

</style>
```

html:

```
<div class="display">some text</div>
<ul class="shtuff">
<li>blueberry </li>
<li>cherry </li>
<li>strawberry  </li>
<li>ferret droppings </li>
</ul>
```

> **$('.display').on('click', 'span', function(){$(this).empty(); });**

is where I can't get it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `remove()` instead of `empty()`.  `remove()` will remove the elements istself where as empty will empty only the `span`s contents.

```
$('.display').on('click', 'span', function () {
      $(this).remove();
 });
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdZHR/)

Comment: I did try that earlier -but you confirmed it works -my problem was also the fact that I had cut/pasted an earlier version of jquery -1.3 any suggestions if I had to develop for a product that didn't make the update?

Comment: That is way too old. I would suggest you to upgrade it.